# Software for Borel-Weil-Bott in positive characteristic?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, mathematical-software, algebraic-groups

I am interested in calculating cohomology of line bundles on flag varieties $G/B$ in positive characteristic. But I really just have a bunch of scattered examples. Does there exist some kind of software that will calculate this for me? For the most part I don't care about the representation structure of the cohomology modules, I just want to know dimensions. Also, I know there are various results on when this cohomology is just like the char. 0 situation, but they won't always apply to my examples. So I don't need general results, just an algorithm.

I just know how to do one example using Macaulay2: irreducible homogeneous bundles on projective space (which are pushforwards of aforementioned line bundles). But I am also interested in things like type D, and homogeneous bundles on Grassmannians.

Comment: Adding a tag algebraic-groups would be useful here.

Answer (score 6):

This is a sort of negative-leaning answer to the question about existence of software for your purpose.    There is quite a bit of history to the problem in prime characteristic, going back to isolated examples found in the 1970s by Mumford and his 1975 Ph.D. student W.L. Griffith Jr. (*Cohomology of Flag Varieties in Characteristic p*) which showed that the classical ideas could break down.    The rank 2 example $G_2$ lends itself to picture drawing and has been looked at in considerable detail.   See the recent updated preprint by Andersen and Kaneda [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3055).

Andersen's clever sheaf cohomology techniques (exploiting the Frobenius map) combined with my more speculative predictions tend to imply that the results depend heavily on Kazhdan-Lusztig theory for the affine Weyl group (of Langlands dual type).   Moreover, the non-vanishing of cohomology seems to involve the actual module structure, so dimensions appear only as a byproduct of the study of generic module filtrations crossing Weyl chamber walls.   The algebraic group of type $G_2$ already indicates how systematic but complicated the results will be in general, so any computational approach must take this case into account.  (The results for $A_2$ and $B_2$ worked out by Andersen following his 1977 MIT thesis *On Schubert Varieties in G/B and Bott's Theorem* are also subtle, but con't compete with the complexity of $G_2$ whose alcove geometry is richer.)

ADDED: The problem arose in the setting of algebraic geometry, as seen in the thesis work mentioned above.   Seshadri wrote up his own version of the $SL_3$ case treated by Larry Griffith, in a typescript *Cohomology of line bundles on $SL_3/B$* (Tata Institute, September 28, 1976).  I learned about the problem from him the following spring at IAS and formulated my own tentative interpretation in a conference paper that summer.  Andersen recovered Griffith's results in a general setting in his 1979 Inventiones paper [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002095068).  In particular, an extra non-vanishing $H^1$ has a unique simple submodule of specified highest weight.   But pinning down the dimension or formal character of this module takes more work, done first by Jantzen (before Kazhdan-Lusztig theory).   There may be shortcuts in small cases, but a general algorithmic approach to the flag variety of $SL_3$ gets complicated.

Comment: I sort of suspected that what I want does not exist. But your answer is still great, and I think I can learn a lot from these references. Also, presumably your reference to Mumford's student is to the paper W. Griffith, "Cohomology of flag varieties in characteristic $p$". This gives the complete answer for $A_2$ (at least for when Bott's theorem fails) with a simple rule and I really like it.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this story, but the cohomology of a homogeneous line bundle on a Grassmannian should be equal to the cohomology of a line bundle on the flag variety in type A corresponding to a weight that vanishes on all but one coroot, which is a very special case. Perhaps there is an algorithm in that case? (There might be some helpful comments in Jantzen's Representations of Algebraic Groups as well).

Answer (score -1):

This may be in the scope of http://sagemath.org/ .